# Django: How to add DeleteView and UpdateView

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm Student in django, i want to add UpdateView and DeleteView, can someone expert guys can help me to figure out (Forum website) :D

i provide some of my views.py code

```
class TopicView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        tid = request.GET.get('id')
        print(tid)
        topic = Topic.objects.filter(id=tid).first()
        print(topic)
        # topic.clicks += 1
        topic.save()
        username = check_result(request, topic)
        print(username)
        comments = topic.comments()
        content = create_content_paginator(request, queryset=comments, page_size=5)
        content.topic = topic
        return render(
           request,
           'topic.html',
            context={'username': username, 'content': content, 'form': Form}
          )

    @check_login
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        topic_id = request.POST.get('topic', '')
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        topic = Topic.objects.filter(id=topic_id).first()
        username = check_result(request, topic)
        if content:
           user = UserInfo.objects.filter(username=username).first()
           comment = Comment(user=user, topic_id=topic_id, content=content)
           comment.save()
        comments = topic.comments()
        content = create_content_paginator(request, queryset=comments, page_size=5)
        content.topic = topic
        print(Form.errors)
        return render(
           request,
          'topic.html',
         context={'username': username, 'content': content, 'form': Form}
    )
```

`tid` = Topic_id of post_id ..
`content` = the content inside the topic

---

```
class PublicView(View):
     @check_login
     def get(self, request, pid, *args, **kwargs):
         subject = Subject.objects.filter(id=pid).first()
         # semester = subject.semester
         username = request.session.get('name')

     return render(
         request,
         'public.html',
         context={'username': username, 'form': Form, 'content': {'subject': subject}}
      )

    @check_login
    def post(self, request, pid, *args, **kwargs):
        subject = Subject.objects.filter(id=pid).first()
        username = request.session.get('name')
        print(username,'asdasd')
        user = UserInfo.objects.filter(username=username).first()
        name = request.POST.get('title')
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        semester_id = request.POST.get('semester_id')
        if pid and name and content and semester_id:

           try:
               topic = Topic(name=name, content=content, subject_id=pid,user=user)
               topic.save()
               red = redirect(f'/topic/?id={topic.id}')

           except Exception as E:
               print(E)
               red = redirect(f'/404/')
           return red

        return render(
            request,
           'public.html',
            context={'username': username, 'form': Form, 'content': {'subject': subject}}

          )
```

Answer (score 0):

To use generic views like CreateView, UpdateView, etc..
You just need to do this:

```
class TopicView(UpdateView):
    model = #enter the name of the model in which you have to make updation.
    fields = #enter the name of the fields in which you have to display in update 
              form. Eg:fields=['name','place']
    template_name = #enter the template name in that you are going to display the 
                     update form
```